# Memory alignment issue in received network packets

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel, network-programming

I'm writing a custom protocol in the linux kernel. I'm using the following structures

```
struct syn {
    __be32 id;      
    __be64 cookie;
};

struct ack {
    __be32 id;      // Right now, setting it to 14 (Just a random choice)
    __be32 sequence;
};

struct hdr {
    ............
    __be32 type;   //last element
};
```

When I send and receive packets, I map the structures `syn` and `ack` (for different packets) to the address of hdr->type.

This should ideally mean that the id (in syn and ack structures) should be mapped to the `hdr->type` and whatever follows the `struct hdr` should be mapped to either `syn->cookie` or `ack->sequence`, depending on which struct I'm mapping on to the `hdr->type`.

But on printing out the memory addresses for these variables, I get the following

```
//For struct syn
hdr->type at ffff880059f55444
syn->id at ffff880059f55444
syn->cookie at ffff880059f5544c  //See the last two bits

//For struct ack_frame
hdr->type at ffff880059f55044
ack->id at ffff880059f55044
ack->sequence at ffff880059f55048  //See the last two bits
```

So why do `syn->cookie` and `ack->sequence` start at different offsets relative to `hdr->type` when `ack->id` and `syn->id` have the same size?

**EDIT 1:** I map these structures using

```
char *ptr = (char *)&hdr->type;
//For syn
struct syn *syn1 = (struct syn *)ptr
//For ack
struct ack *ack1 = (struct ack *)ptr
```

Comment: key word here is *alignment*...

Comment: What do you mean by "I map the structures syn and ack (for different packets) to the address of hdr->type."? I smell undefined behavior for accessing an object with an lvalue of a type that is not the effective type of the object and/or accessing out of bounds.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I need a way to make sure that I can access the packet the same way each time, even if I've filled it using different structures

Comment: Why do you do this? Why don't you just write code that does what you actually want to do rather than trying to make it happen by magic?

Comment: I'm trying to write code that does what I want. I was trying to understand the behavior of the code I wrote, not really expecting magic here.

Answer (score 1):

since you work in 64 bits the compiler fills struct the following:

```
struct syn {
    uint32_t id
    uint32_t hole -- the compiler must add here cause it mist align
    uint64_t seq
}
```

I guess the data doesn't have holes, so to fix it you will need to set seq to uint32_t and cast it later.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try this and report :)

Comment: I believe however, that this will make memory access slow [read here](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)

Answer (score 1):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#Common-Type-Attributes

Look at `packed`. For whatever reason, GCC doesn't let me link directly to that section.

Comment: pack will squeeze it but it will change the order of the struct. so the pointers won't fit.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your structure as following. Attribute packed means allignment should be as 1 byte.
Following structure will be 12 bytes longs. If you dont use "attribyte" key word, your structure would be 16 bytes long.

```
struct yours{
 __be32 id;      
 __be64 cookie;
}__attribute__((__packed__));
```